insert datetime value to surrealdb table whith python
I want insert this:
{'date': '2023-07-03T07:18:52.841147', 'open': 27430.0, 'high': 27730.0, 'low': 27420.0, 'close': 27720.0, 'final': 27490.0, 'y_final': 27190.0, 'vol': 713407.0, 'val': 19755901740.0, 'count': 560.0, 'ins': 'instrument:IRO1ABIK0001'}

Record to database, but receive this error:
surrealdb.ws.SurrealPermissionException: There was a problem with the database: Found '2023-07-03T07:18:52.841147' for field date, with record 
trade:mb5zls5xah1xyo4rsa1o, but expected a datetime.

How can fixed it?
insert datetime value to surrealdb table with Python.
my code is
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
from surrealdb import Surreal


async def inser_trade():
    async with Surreal("ws://localhost:8000/rpc") as db:
        await db.signin({"user": "root", "pass": "root"})
        await db.use("algo_trading", "algo_trading")
        record = {
            'date': '2023-07-03T07:18:52.841147',
            'open': 27430.0,
            'high': 27730.0,
            'low': 27420.0,
            'close': 27720.0,
            'final': 27490.0,
            'y_final': 27190.0,
            'vol': 713407.0,
            'val': 19755901740.0,
            'count': 560.0,
            'ins': 'instrument:IRO1ABIK0001'
        }
        result = await db.create('trade', record)

asyncio.run(inser_trade())

and when convert date to datetime.fromisoformat, raise this error.
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
my code is
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
from surrealdb import Surreal


async def inser_trade():
    async with Surreal("ws://localhost:8000/rpc") as db:
        await db.signin({"user": "root", "pass": "root"})
        await db.use("algo_trading", "algo_trading")
        record = {
            'date': '2023-07-03T07:18:52.841147',
            'open': 27430.0,
            'high': 27730.0,
            'low': 27420.0,
            'close': 27720.0,
            'final': 27490.0,
            'y_final': 27190.0,
            'vol': 713407.0,
            'val': 19755901740.0,
            'count': 560.0,
            'ins': 'instrument:IRO1ABIK0001'
        }
        record['date'] = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(record['date'])
        result = await db.create('trade', record)


asyncio.run(inser_trade())


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You did not supply code as for your example but based on the error it seems that something is wrong with how you pass in the datetime data.
Here is a dummy example of how you might solve it, try to implement it in your use case, and hope it will help:
from datetime import datetime
from surrealdb import Surreal

db = Surreal("<Connect to your db like so or in any other way you choose>")

record = {
    'date': datetime.fromisoformat('2023-07-03T07:18:52.841147').isoformat(),  # Convert datetime to ISO string
    'open': 27430.0,
    'high': 27730.0,
    'low': 27420.0,
    'close': 27720.0,
    'final': 27490.0,
    'y_final': 27190.0,
    'vol': 713407.0,
    'val': 19755901740.0,
    'count': 560.0,
    'ins': 'instrument:IRO1ABIK0001'
}
# Insert the record
result = await db.create('trade', record)
print(result)


It doesn't work. TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

Can you share the code you've used?

Shared it-update question.

@یاقوب I updated the code, try now

surrealdb.ws.SurrealPermissionException: There was a problem with the database: Found '2023-07-03T07:18:52.841147' for field date, with record trade:5g8su5j5c6u0oe0iy196, but expected a datetime

SurrealDB requires type casting. The following works:
{"time": d'2023-12-25T08:00:00Z'}
However, this is incorrect JSON. If make it correct:
{"time": "d'2023-12-25T08:00:00Z'"}
get an error message:

"Found "d'2023-12-25T08:00:00Z'" for field time, with record transaction:i2aoe422ftuv3ot01ke5, but expected a datetime"

Incorrect JSON format works OK in Surrealist, however it is useless in Python. Couldn’t find a solution for this.
